# ASP.NET Treeview control always appending nodes to CheckedNodes list

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have an ASP.NET treeview on my page. In my codebehind I have the following method:

```
public string GetSelectedTreeValues(TreeView tv)
    {
        string taxVal = string.Empty;

        StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string lists = string.Empty;
        string cleanedlists = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            TreeNodeCollection checkedNodes = tv.CheckedNodes;
            foreach (TreeNode tn in checkedNodes)
            {
                lists = textBuilder.Append(tn.ValuePath + ",").ToString();
            }

            // removing any trailing commas
            cleanedlists = lists.Substring(0, lists.Trim().Length - 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new ApplicationException("Error: Getting Tree Nodes", ex);
        }
        return cleanedlists;
    }
```

The problem is when I do a postback, if I change the values I've selected, they always *append* to the list of values. I thought the list of values should *clear*, then reset to the new values.

I've stepped through the code and found the CheckedNodes property is always appending the nodes I check to the list without removing unchecked nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the part of code that does the treeview binding ?

At which point during page lifecycle are binding and GetSelectedTreeValues called ?

If you can, you should replace the try block content with

```
        cleanedlists = string.Join(",", tv.CheckedNodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Select(tn => tn.ValuePath).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, JBL! Your solution worked - now I can use the valuepaths to set the nodes to be checked across postbacks! :D (Which is what I needed to accomplish)

Comment: I spoke too soon...it looks like I *still* wind up with the treeview appending to the CheckedNodes collection, no matter what I do. This is driving me nuts - why won't the values update when I uncheck the boxes?

Comment: @Tim : the problem does not seem to be in this part of the code. Could you please post the other parts relative to your treeview ?

Comment: Found it - I had some code writing to a cookie that was checking the checkboxes on me...